# Unreal Engine Size on Disk

Tags: unreal-4, installer

I want to install Unreal Engine 4 from the epic game launcher but I have the following problem: If I want to install the engine after about 50% it says I don't have enough space on my disk, and if I look up how much space the folder took it says 75 GB is that normal?[image]

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/66825/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk

Comment: I know that the space on disk is bigger but why is it so huge for only one version?

Comment: Maybe the cluster size of your disk is very big. If that's so, this symptom would show on other parts of your file system (on that disk). If it's not, then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

No it is way too much!
I have three engines installed and they take around ~80+gb

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I just added pictures and it says the size is 14 GB but the size on the disk is 75 GB and I am  very confused why this is the case.